# class-validator doesn't validate data

Tags: nestjs

I installed `class-validator`, `class-transformer` and in my login method I use validation, but it does not work.

This is the method that I'm using:

```js
@Post('login')
async login(@Body() userReq:LoginDto){
    return await this.userService.login(userReq)
}
```

This the login DTO:

```js
import { IsEmail, IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class LoginDto {
     @IsEmail() @IsNotEmpty({message:"email !!!"})
    email:string;
   
    password:string;
}
```

When I request insomnia without email, instead having a Bad Request Exception, I have the Not Found undefined (email is undefined).

`emitDecoratorMetadata: true` is enabled.

Happy for any help.

Comment: how did you set up the validation pipe?

Comment: that is all i do for validation

Comment: the docs is pretty easy to follow btw: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#auto-validation

Comment: thank you very much brother i find the solution . i had to add this : app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe()); in the main method  thank you